# How to remove a substring wrapped by slashes like "/foo/"?

Tags: php, string, replace, slash

It's a nooby question and I know it is a common question but I don't find it.
I'm trying to remove the substring `/The Foo/` in a string `Word/Word2/The Foo/`.
I know the problem is about the slash caracter but I don't manage to find how to write the pattern.

I tried :

1. `preg_replace( "/(/The Foo/)/", "", $str);`
2. `preg_replace( "/The Foo/", "", $str);`
3. `str_replace( "/The Foo/", "", $str )`
   ...

...without success.

Comment: 3 should definitely work.  2 won't work because the / is being used as the regex delimiter

Comment: 3 does not work. I don't know why.

Comment: $str must not be what you think it is then.  var_dump it or use a debugger.

Comment: Could you show the part of code where you use `str_replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected, provided you give a different delimiter in regex:

```
str_replace( "/The Foo/", "", $str )
// or using regex, using +  as the delimiter instead of /
preg_replace( "+/The Foo/+", "", $str )
```

Proof: https://3v4l.org/mjXgE

Answer (score 0):

str_replace( "/The Foo/", "", $str ) seems to work in reality.

The problem was I print two separate strings without space:

1. `Word/Word2/`
2. `The Foo/`

There was an illusion of one string but there are two strings.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you need something like:

```
str_replace( "The Foo", "", $str ); //Word/Word2//
```

or

```
str_replace( "/The Foo/", "", $str );//Word/Word2
```